# Solve Equation for n where n is the power ($3^n = \frac{1}{81}$)

Tags: exponentiation

I have the equation: $$3^n = \frac{1}{81}$$

And I need to find n.
Can someone explain how I do this, with steps please (*GCSE level*)?

TIA.

Comment: Can you solve $3^k=81$?

Comment: @lulu Nope, sorry :/

Comment: Ok...can you write out the first few powers?  $3^0,3^1,3^2,3^3, 3^4,\cdots$?

Comment: GCSE. If $n$ is a positive integer then clearly there are no solutions. But if $n$ is a negative integer, say $n=-k$, then we have $3^n=\frac{1}{3^k}$. So we want a positive integer with $3^k=81$. So now follow lulu's hints.

Comment: @MattCowley If you can't solve lulu's question, then your deficiencies won't be solved by asking stuff here. You need to ask someone to help you in person.

Comment: WHat is GCSE? Something secondary school?

Comment: @Joanpemo http://bfy.tw/5gyS

Comment: If you dont know how to solve this I honestly think that it will be better try to learn about exponentiation at GCSE level, maybe through youtube vids or online courses. You can write $\frac1{81}=\frac1{3^4}=3^{-4}$

Comment: @lulu Yes, got it now. Thanks!

Comment: @MattCowley Thanks, but I don't really care that much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that $81 = 3^4$

Then $\frac{1}{3^4} = 3^n$

Then $n = -4$

Answer (score 0):

After doing some googling I learnt that

$$ b^y = x  \therefore  log_b(x) = y $$

So then

$$ 3^n = \frac{1}{81}  \therefore  log_3(\frac{1}{81}) = n = -4 $$

Comment: @luísa-borsato 's method is much better.